# How to change the URL of a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

By default, my URL was set to example.com/wp/wp-admin instead of the example.com/wp-admin that I used to remember. Also my website's contents show on example.com/wp rather than example.com. How do I change the url as well as changing `wp-admin` to something of my preference?

Answer (score 3):

Two questions in 1 ;)

For the first one, redirect `example.com/wp` to `example.com`, you must first set your domain to point to the wp directory rather than to its parent directory (www, htdocs...). Then you will have to set the new adress (without `/wp`) into wordpress Settings via the dashboard or phpMyAdmin (wp_options table).

For the second question, at this point, your wp-admin will be accessible via `example.com/wp-admin`. If you want to change it for custom slug, you will save time using a plugin.